# swfLoader vs mx Image

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex3, flex4.5

I have an application that I'm migrating from flex 3 to flex 4.5. In this application, there is some mx Image components that load a simple swf file (image). Spark image doesn't load swf files, so I was wondering, should I keep the mx Image, or should I change it to SWFLoader? Is there any advantages to using one or the other?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reading Adobe documentation about [Image control](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WSc5cd04c102ae3e97-33ad5caa12c719dc7c8-8000.html):

> Adobe Flex supports several image formats, including GIF, JPEG, and
>   PNG. You can import these images into your applications by using the
>   Spark Image control or BitmapImage. To load SWF files, you use the
>   SWFLoader control.
>
> The Image control is part of both MX and Spark component sets. While
>   you can use the MX Image control in your application, Adobe recommends
>   that you use the Spark Image control instead.

As it states and recommends, it's better to use the spark architecture, instead the mx one (whenever it's possible. It's not a good idead to mix spark and mx components, but Adobe has not migrated every single component to spark yet). I'll go for `<s:SWFLoader />` (which is already a new nomenclature for `<mx:SWFLoader />`.)

Comment: Well, thats the thing with swfloader, its the same component but with a different nomenclature, so why should i use swf loader instead of mx image

Comment: For the very same reason I told you in the answer: to have only one architecture supported (spark). It's a matter or cleanliness. Anyways, It's up to you, considering that `<mx:Image />` extends `<mx:SWFLoader />`.